# ItemStateChanged called twice into JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcombobox

Hello and i am using one Combobox and when i triggered IteamStateChage event then that action called twice. but if i called twice i can not make make it possible what i want to do.

So is there any way to called IteamStatechange evet only once. when i change iteam into the Jcombobox. i just need once action of itemStatechange. and using Item State change only.![Here Screen Shot for same.][1]

please help me for same.
and thank you for you ans in advance.

Comment: Can you show your some code where you think this is occurring? Better yet, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Did you by accident register two listeners to the combo box?

Comment: look into the Screen Shot its occur twice. as output shows. so its called twice. cant u see out put??

Comment: ItemStateChanged events can be trigger twice as it deals with the deselection of the current value and selection of the new one. This the default behaviour. You need to inspect the state event to determine what type of event it is...

Comment: @peeskillet see the Screen Shot there is right behind the code is there for the iteam statechage.

Comment: @MadProgrammer so what is the solution for that its giving Two call to server. so its working efficiency is cause. so how to give one call only?

Comment: Read the [available documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html)

Comment: Use ActionListener instead of ItemListener

Comment: Ya i have read that documentation but i need only one call at all. that wont help me that documentation. bcoz that isnt solution. i need solution can u give some ans or suggestion so how could i make single call out of it.?

Comment: @laksys but it only use for actionperformed events na. how could i use it there and i am using neteans so that wont let me change that.

Comment: The solution is document in the [ItemEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html) documentation.

Comment: Ohh i can see it now. :D really dude you are Mad Programmer Awesome :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this context, this is expected behaviour. The combobox is signaling the deselection of the current item and the selection of the new item.

In the `itemStateChanged` method, you need to inspect the state of the `ItemEvent` to determine what you should do.

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {

    switch (evt.getStateChanged()) {
        case ItemEvent.DESELECTED:
            // Do what ever you want when the item is deselected
            break;
        case ItemEvent.SELECTED:
            // Do what ever you want when the item is selected
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for MadProgramming. :D awesome dude. btw where you From MasProgrammer?

Comment: @Krishna If there was a bright center to the universe... ;). I live in the some times sunny town of Melbourne, Victoria in Australia...

Comment: Someone thinks pretty highly of themselves :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer ohhh :D haha right. but yar really i have to say u r mad Programmer. and ya btw now will ask you all query about this.

Comment: @peeskillet ...I'm in the city that it's furthest from ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer really but u got my Solution quite fast. and ya thank you for your answer and ya its look like you are to much experience in this. sorry for being rude haan i was worried for solution..:P

Comment: @Krishna 15 years of coding in a particular API will do that - still have lots to learn though (me that is) ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  ohhh great Sir. :) i like to have tips.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how to determin if the change event is Select or Deselect:

```
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"one", "two", "foo"});
 comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
     @Override
     public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
         System.out.println("Change");
         if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
             System.out.println("Selected");
         }
         if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED){
             System.out.println("Deselected");
         } 
     }
 });
```

Comment: Well let me check.. :)